# How to Crop the image in android marshmallow by using default crop intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, crop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-crop

In my application requirement is select the image from gallery and then crop the selected image and set to the imageview. Below is my sample code for cropping the image.

```
//call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");
    //indicate image type and Uri
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(mImageCaptureUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    //retrieve data on return
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
    cropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
   startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

Above code is works fine in below android marshmallow devises but android marsh mallow it is crashing.How to solve the issue?

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for reply,is android marshmallow does not have crop intent?

Comment: @CommonsWare i tried to add cropping libraries but app size increases.That is the reason i am looking for default crop

Comment: No version of the Android OS has a `CROP` `Intent`. You are using an undocumented unsupported `Intent` action originally created for a specific camera app. *Some* other camera apps may support that `Intent`. *Some* Android devices may ship with one of these camera apps. But there are *thousands* of Android device models, and not all of them will have an app pre-installed that supports this `Intent`. "That is the reason i am looking for default crop" -- **there is no "default crop" in Android**.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you,Please suggest any cropping library?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement camera and gallery with cropping is to use library.in market there are so many third party library are available but none of them work for all devices.
There is one library is available which is stable across the deferent and several companies devices.
https://github.com/biokys/cropimage  use this demo.
This is very old library but it is stable across the all different devices.